# How to eliminate duplicates in my query if both of them having status as Canceled (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

if someone could help to add some statement in this query that would eliminate duplicate if their status are both canceled. Highligted in the image below of the sample that i don't want to appear in my query results.

```
with cte0 AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM efleet_copy AS e1
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT mta_id, COUNT(mta_id) FROM efleet_copy WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM service_date) = 02 AND mta_id LIKE '_________'
     GROUP BY mta_id HAVING COUNT(mta_id) > 1) AS e2
    ON e1.mta_id = e2.mta_id
    WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM service_date) = 02
    ORDER BY e1.mta_id ASC, e1.ride_id ASC, e1.trip_number ASC
)
SELECT * FROM cte0 c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM cte0 ci
    WHERE c.ride_id = ci.ride_id
    AND status = 'Approved'
    GROUP BY ride_id 
    HAVING SUM(trip_total_amount) = 0::money
)
```

[image: sample data]

Comment: Eliminate both or eliminate dups (keeping one)? Also, how to know if it is dup? Can you provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? (it has no sense to force people to work with your data, make some effort to generalize your question for all future users )

Comment: They are duplicates when they have exactly the same data except trip_total_amount. Like what is highlighted in the image both transaction is canceled so i don't need them in my results but i don't want to completely eliminate all canceled because sometimes there is some duplicates which is a canceled and approved.

Comment: Can you post the simplest sample. With minimum columns but enough to extrapolate a possible answer to your scenario? With an easy semantic for everyone, like `order number`, `order status`, ...

Comment: It would help to have sample data and results for the scenarios you mentioned @jpabiado

Answer (score 1):

You could try the DISTINCT clause, so your query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    rate, 
    status,
    ride_id,
    trip_number,
    mta_id,
    service_date,
    service_start,
    driver_id,
    cab_number,
    trip_total_amount
FROM cte0 c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM cte0 ci
    WHERE c.ride_id = ci.ride_id
    AND status = 'Approved'
    GROUP BY ride_id 
    HAVING SUM(trip_total_amount) = 0::money
);
```

Comment: I tried this also but what it does is they just stacked all the canceled transactions at the lower portion of the query results. It helps somehow but i need something more solid. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What do you mean stack all cancelled transactions at the lower portion? Are the records you are expecting are there? If the issue is with where the records are placed, then you can use ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

The `DISTINCT` clause allows you to remove the duplicate rows.

try `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: But they are not exactly duplicates, their are some field of data which they have difference with each other like for example in the image 'trip_total_amount'

Comment: try `(regexp_replace(trip_total_amount, '\D','','g'), '')::numeric AS result` to remove non-numeric characters from 'trip_total_amount' @jpabiado

Comment: \D being the class shorthand for "not a digit".
And you need the 4th parameter 'g' (for "globally") to replace all occur

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM cte0 c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM cte0 ci
                  WHERE c.ride_id = ci.ride_id AND
                        status = 'Approved'
                  GROUP BY ride_id 
                  HAVING SUM(trip_total_amount) = 0::money
                 ) OR
      (c.status = 'Canceled' AND
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM cte0 ci
               WHERE c.ride_id = ci.ride_id AND
                     ci.status = 'Canceled' AND
                     ci.trip_total_amount = - c.trip_total_amount
              )
      )
```

The problem is a little bit unclear.  I would approach all the logic using window functions, but you have already started with `exists` subqueries, so this follows in that spirit.

Comment: thanks for your inputs but when i tried this it runs but the query results still shows those canceled duplicate transactions

Comment: @jpabiado . . . Did you spell "Canceled" correctly?

Comment: the data i am using uses that word that's why i use it in my queries

Comment: @jpabiado . . . My original answer spelled it incorrectly.